# Block users from installing or running programs in Windows using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My company currently has 2 computers out of 10 that the user can sign in to the PC using there Office 365 credentials. I am the only admin on our account everyone else is a standard user. Now one of the PC's when the user tries to download and run an exe program the pc will notify the user Via Windows Installer message that they are not a Global Admin and the pc will require my global admin credentials. Now the other PC which was set up from the beginning as a company owned device that will require the user to sign in with there office 365 credentials. But this pc allows the user to download exe programs without global admin permission. Both pc's have windows 10, managed via Intune and are in the same policy groups in Intune. I am aware that when you set up a user using this process the PC will have them set up as an admin on the PC which you can not change to a standard user but the first pc is set up this way and it requires a global admin to run exe files. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but it's not a topic for StackOverflow: this is a programming Q&A site. Maybe ask on SuperUser?

Comment: ok. will do....

Answer (score 0):

You should join your win10 devices to Azure AD before you can sign in these computers with Azure AD/Office 365 credentials.

During joining, the user his/her Azure AD account will become the local admin on that computer. At the meanwhile, the user who has been assigned the **Global Admin role** will also have local admin rights by default. Besides these two kinds of users, the other Azure AD users only have local users rights so they will not be able to run the installer.

You can confirm if these office 365 accounts have local admin rights on these two computers by looking into Local Users and Groups->Groups->Administrators.

Comment: How do I join the Win10 device to Azure AD without using my AD/Office 365 credentials?

Comment: Unfortunately at this moment it's not possible to join Azure AD without using Azure AD credentials.